# How can I mix audio tracks together in a PHP script?

Tags: php, linux, audio, command-line-interface

I'm looking to write a PHP script which takes a long backing track audio file and mixes in other shorter tracks at certain time intervals.

I guess I'll be looking for a linux based CLI tool which PHP can interface with?

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is  command line too you can use with php:
http://sox.sourceforge.net/